# .tabViewStyle with animated swiping of tabs

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

Is it possible somehow to use the .tabViewStyle(.page) for animating swiping between tabs but with a look as the default style?

Basically I want the animated tab swiping but not the tiny centered tab icons that comes as a side effect of using .page instead of the default TabView.

The page feature seems more for swiping similar objects, not different tabs, but the swipe animation looks great, which is what I'm after.

Thanks!
Marcus

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you trying to get a TavView with swiping left and right?  What "default style" are you trying to avoid?  The dots at the bottom of the screen?